# Is there a way to create an editable list in a separate tab for automated content?

Tags: google-sheets, automation

I have a CSV that is pulling in content automatically and am wondering if there is a way to assign values to the 'Title' and 'Colour' variants in a list in the second tab, rather than editing the formula each time I would like to add a new Title or Colour.

The 'Title' and 'Colour' variants are determined by values assigned in column N. I would like, if possible, to create new Colours and Titles and assign them values in a list in the second tab.

I have created an example CSV with the necessary columns highlighted.

`Column B - Product title` `Column I - Colour`

**Link to CSV**

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1c8TyIL_GGtyIEWV6igNzM705cSt4nSTIpGuUl_UTN1w/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

B1: `=arrayformula(IF(A1:A="Handle","Title",VLOOKUP(INDEX(SPLIT(N1:N, "-"),,1),Title,2,false)))`

I1: `=arrayformula(IF(A1:A="Handle","Colour",VLOOKUP(INDEX(SPLIT(N1:N, "-"),,2),Colour,2,false)))`

**I added "false".**

Comment: Thank you Boris, I appreciate the help. It seems to be having trouble pulling in some of the values. I've tested a couple of new Colours and Titles but can't seem to get them to work.

Comment: To simplify the formula, I've added 2 named ranges Color (A: B) and Title (D:E). Try again please

Comment: Codes 1, 2 in column A were entered not as numbers, but as text: = "1", = "2". I have corrected.

Comment: That works! Thank you so much for your help, I cannot describe how much you've helped me out here.

Comment: I added FALSE to the formula because the values in the Colour codes are not sorted. 
I'm glad I was able to help. Good luck!